# understanding lock in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

Please help me to understand the flow of lock in c#.
 A class with methods is continuously calling by two different threads periodically.

```
class DataRetriever
{
   BaseUrl="...";
   public static void _Fetch(<list<dataInformation> quote)
   {
      XDocument doc=XDocument.Load(BaseUrl);
      parse(quote,doc);
   }

   private static void Parse(List<dataInformation> quotes, XDocument doc)
   {
       // some statement
   }
}

// dataInformation is a class here
```

Now Questions are...
1. Is there any need of lock statement here or not if _Fetch() method is being called by two or more threads periodically. If yes please tell me why and how? I want to understand lock flow.
2. Why we use object to be locked?

I've tried here

```
class DataRetriever
{
   BaseUrl="...";

   object obj=new object()
   public static void _Fetch(<list<dataInformation> quote)
   {
      lock(obj) // giving error obj is not accepting here
      {
         XDocument doc=XDocument.Load(BaseUrl);
         parse(quote,doc);
      }
   }

   private static void Parse(List<dataInformation> quotes, XDocument doc)
   {
       // some statement
   }
}
```

Also tried to solve

```
class DataRetriever
{
   BaseUrl="...";

   public static void _Fetch(<list<dataInformation> quote)
   {
      lock(this) // giving error this is not accepting
      {
         XDocument doc=XDocument.Load(BaseUrl);
         parse(quote,doc);
      }
   }

   private static void Parse(List<dataInformation> quotes, XDocument doc)
   {
       // some statement
   }
}
```

Do the needful. please provide me some useful link if possible.
regards

Comment: lock is not require in your case as you're not sharing any states between your threads.

Comment: It is an static method.. I've just deleted it and create it an instance method it is accepting now.

Comment: thanks @Tien Dinh.. can you please give me some links regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

This is correct but you should really pay attention to errors that prevent compiling.

your object obj=new object(); was missing the ;

```
class DataRetriever
{
   BaseUrl="...";

   object obj=new object();
   public void _Fetch(<list<dataInformation> quote)
   {
      lock(obj) // giving error obj is not accepting here
      {
         XDocument doc=XDocument.Load(BaseUrl);
         parse(quote,doc);
      }
   }

   private void Parse(List<dataInformation> quotes, XDocument doc)
   {
       // some statement
   }
}
```

As mentioned below you also use an instanced field with static methods. I simply changed the methods to non static.

Comment: That's not the problem. OP uses instance field in a static method.

Comment: Thanks I didn't even notice that. I will update to reflect changes.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving an error because you're trying to use an `this` which reflects the **current instance** of your type inside a **static method**, which belongs to your type, not your instance.

A static method on a non-static class will result in only the static fields to be initialized via a static constructor (if one exists) or via field initialization. That is why your use of `this` isn't allowed inside your method.

The alternative could be to create a static field for a lock. Note this will mean that this lock object will be shared among all instances of your class.

```
public static object _lock = new object();
```

And then:

```
lock(_lock)
{
    XDocument doc=XDocument.Load(BaseUrl);
    parse(quote,doc);
}
```

Comment: Thanks But, another question is this lock needed over here or not?

Comment: Currently, i can't possibly know that. It depends on what your `Parse` method does, how threads are accessing your code, etc.

Comment: Parse method here is just a linq to xml query. with a foreach loop. where _Fetch method is being called by two different methods in two different classes and threads simultaneously.

Comment: Does it have any shared resources being accessed from multiple threads?

Comment: hmmm... As threading is not very well known by me but, I think yes sure. But, its early to say. I'll keep you in touch as soon my project grows. thanks.